# How can I configure Redmine to create or update new issues via email?

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails, g-suite, redmine

What I need:

- Anonymous user should be able to submit a new issue via email and Redmine should do it's best to parse the email and add a new issue.
- You should be able to reply to email notifications redmine sends out.  Redmine should be able to handle this.  At the minimum a user should be able to reply to one of these notifications and their reply will be added as a comment.  More functionality would be welcome.  As would the ability (w/ documentations and code examples) to hack up some ruby to create a custom parser/handler to do some other action would be awesome as well.
- If this could work with our existing Google Apps (paid/business edition) setup that would be even better

I've spent some time googling for this and even asking in #redmine on freenode with no luck.  All I found was this /srv/redmine/extra/mail_handler/mail-handler.rb but no documentation anywhere and the comments aren't all that helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the page you are looking for: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails

- Anonymous issue creation is covered
  on that page
- Read the "How it works" section on what all it can do
- It will work with basically any POP or IMAP box you can give it.

P.S. Please stick around IRC for a bit before going offline :)